# register classes\interfaces along the execution stack

Tags: autofac

If you have multiple prpjects, and some projects do not have a reference to others, e.g. service layer has no reference to the data access layer, how do you register classes\interfaces as you move along the execution stack?

Comment: You do this by registering everything inside the application's [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). See this q/a for more about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps I'm missing something here. Are you saying that I should be registering all interfaces at the beginning of the execution stack. But would that not just use up resources if I don't use all of them? Or are you also saying that they will be "lazy registered"?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you should register all your classes in Autofac at _application startup_ and inside the _Composition Root_. The Composition Root is located in each _startup project_. In case you have multiple startup projects (e.g. web service, web app, WPF app, etc), you will have multiple Composition Roots. But do _not_ register your classes anywhere else but in those startup projects.